# How can I obtain the individual elements of a heterogeneous list without knowing their type?

Tags: rust, type-level-computation

Given an implementation of a heterogeneous list in `rust` (for example like the one from `frunk`), how can I obtain a reference to an element within the list without knowing the concrete type of the element? The length of the list is known statically, but cannot be hard-coded as numeric literal.

I have tried to obtain the individual elements by popping each element off the list sequentially (as shown in the code example) and by writing an indexing method that accepts a `usize` index as argument. Neither attempts even compile. The posted example is what I would *like* to do.

```rust
pub trait HList: Sized {
    const LEN: usize;

    type Head;
    type Tail: HList;

    fn push<E>(self, element: E) -> Element<E, Self> {
        Element { head: element, tail: self }
    }

    fn pop(self) -> Option<(Self::Head, Self::Tail)>;

    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        Self::LEN
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Default, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
pub struct Element<H, T> {
    pub head: H,
    pub tail: T,
}

impl<H, T: HList> HList for Element<H, T> {
    const LEN: usize = 1 + <T as HList>::LEN;

    type Head = H;
    type Tail = T;

    fn pop(self) -> Option<(H, T)> {
        Some((self.head, self.tail))
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, Default, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
pub struct End;

impl HList for End {
    const LEN: usize = 0;

    type Head = End;
    type Tail = End;

    fn pop(self) -> Option<(Self::Head, Self::Tail)> {
        None
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn pop_two_for() {
        let h = End
            .push(0usize)
            .push(String::from("Hello, World"));

        fn eval<H: HList>(l: H) {
            for _ in 0usize..H::LEN {
                let (e, l) = l.pop().unwrap();
                // Do work with `e`.
            }
        }

        eval(h);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a reasonable recursive solution, but it only works out if I can modify the `HList` trait based on the trait requirements of the work to be done. This is fine for my use case, even if it's not as generic as I would have liked it to be.

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;

pub trait MyCustomTrait<'a>: Debug {}

impl<'a> MyCustomTrait<'a> for () {}

impl<'a> MyCustomTrait<'a> for usize {}

impl<'a> MyCustomTrait<'a> for String {}

pub trait HList: Sized {
    const LEN: usize;

    type Head: for<'a> MyCustomTrait<'a>;
    type Tail: HList;

    fn push<E>(self, element: E) -> Element<E, Self>
    where
        E: for<'a> MyCustomTrait<'a>,
    {
        Element::new(element, self)
    }

    fn head(&self) -> &Self::Head;

    fn tail(&self) -> &Self::Tail;

    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        Self::LEN
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Default, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
pub struct Element<H, T>(H, T);

impl<H, T: HList> Element<H, T> {
    pub fn new(head: H, tail: T) -> Self {
        Element(head, tail)
    }
}

impl<H, T> HList for Element<H, T>
where
    H: for<'a> MyCustomTrait<'a>,
    T: HList,
{
    const LEN: usize = 1 + <T as HList>::LEN;

    type Head = H;
    type Tail = T;

    fn head(&self) -> &Self::Head {
        &self.0
    }

    fn tail(&self) -> &Self::Tail {
        &self.1
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, Default, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
pub struct End;

impl HList for End {
    const LEN: usize = 0;

    type Head = ();
    type Tail = End;

    fn head(&self) -> &Self::Head {
        &()
    }

    fn tail(&self) -> &Self::Tail {
        &End
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn artbitrary_recursive() {
        let h = End
            .push(0usize)
            .push(String::from("Hello, World"));

        fn eval<H: HList>(list: &H) {
            if H::LEN > 0 {
                let head = list.head();
                // Do work here, like print the debug representation of `head`.
                eprintln!("{:?}", head);

                eval(list.tail());
            }
        }

        eval(&h);
        assert!(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just in case somebody is interested; I used this heterogeneous list in my case to register types with a container that stores instances of these types via dynamic typing (through `std::any::Any`). This allows me to keep the container open to adding external types, while enabling (de)-serialization of the entire structure.